# Should I post a playable demo on Kickstarter?

Tags: alpha, playtesting, fund-raising

I am asking this question way in advance of my progress, but I am still curious and would like if to know in case I ever make it this far. So I'll phrase this hypothetically in the future.

The game I am making has a fully functional demo. It has programmer art and only one level. All of the "extra" features are missing. It is bug free and the core mechanics are fully implemented, but there are very few enemy types, and planned features like a leveling system are missing.

For game designers, it is relatively clear what the game will be, as the mechanics are clearly seen and understood. But I don't know how it will be perceived by non-game designers.

When I look at other kick starters, I have seen video game kickstarters that range from only text, to videos of developers talking about the game, to videos of actual gameplay. But I have not seen a single link to a playable demo.

Would it help or hurt to link to the playable demo that would show where the game is headed? Would the potential funders look at the unpolishedness of it and write it off, or would they take it for what it is: a concept?

Comment: Could be construed as opinion base, but there is a black and white answer: would it statistically result in higher funding or lower funding?

Comment: Find a statistically significant sample set of identical games in identical markets that did and did not offer playable demos, and maybe you'll get a "black and white" answer.  But obviously that's impossible, so there's no "correct" answer.